# Infinispan 14.0.2 vulnerabilities

Tags: infinispan

i have scanned the latest version of infinispan 14.0.2 with our twistcli(Prisma Cloud) and found some vulnerabilities:

```
+------------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|       CVE        | SEVERITY  | CVSS |                   PACKAGE                   |    VERSION    |          STATUS          | PUBLISHED  | DISCOVERED |                            DESCRIPTION                            | TRIGGERED FAILURE |
+------------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| CVE-2022-45047   | critical  | 9.00 | org.apache.sshd_sshd-common                 | 2.7.0         | fixed in 2.9.2           | 12 days    | < 1 hour   | Class                                                             | Yes               |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               | 12 days ago              |            |            | org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider |                   |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               |                          |            |            | in Apache MINA SSHD <= 2.9.1 uses Java deserialization to load a  |                   |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               |                          |            |            | serialized ja...                                                  |                   |
+------------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| PRISMA-2022-0239 | high      | 7.50 | com.squareup.okhttp3_okhttp                 | 3.14.9        | fixed in 4.9.2           | > 4 months | < 1 hour   | com.squareup.okhttp3_okhttp packages prior                        | No                |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               | > 4 months ago           |            |            | to version 4.9.2 are vulnerable for sensitive                     |                   |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               |                          |            |            | information disclosure. An illegal character in a                 |                   |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               |                          |            |            | header valu...                                                    |                   |
+------------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| CVE-2022-42004   | high      | 7.50 | com.fasterxml.jackson.core_jackson-databind | 2.13.3        | fixed in 2.13.4          | 58 days    | < 1 hour   | In FasterXML jackson-databind before 2.13.4,                      | No                |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               | 58 days ago              |            |            | resource exhaustion can occur because of a lack of                |                   |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               |                          |            |            | a check in BeanDeserializer._deserializeFromArray                 |                   |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               |                          |            |            | to p...                                                           |                   |
+------------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| CVE-2022-42003   | high      | 7.50 | com.fasterxml.jackson.core_jackson-databind | 2.13.3        | fixed in 2.14.0          | 58 days    | < 1 hour   | In FasterXML jackson-databind before 2.14.0-rc1,                  | No                |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               | 58 days ago              |            |            | resource exhaustion can occur because of a lack of                |                   |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               |                          |            |            | a check in primitive value deserializers to avoid                 |                   |
|                  |           |      |                                             |               |                          |            |            | ...                                                               |                   |
+------------------+-----------+------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+

Vulnerabilities found for image infinispan:14.0.2: total - 5, critical - 1, high - 4, medium - 0, low - 0
Vulnerability threshold check results: FAIL
Scan failed due to vulnerability policy violations: ITMP, 1 vulnerabilities, [critical:1]
```

please fix  it otherwise we cannot use it in our environment because the vulnerability scanner blocks the deployment.

expectation: image is free of vulnerability.

Comment: Not really sure why you believe Stackoverflow can fix this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Issues like these should be reported to the project itself using its issue tracker or discussion tools. For Infinispan that would be https://issues.redhat.com/projects/ISPN/issues and https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/discussions/